# What is the role of the @ character in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

As used for instance in this macro definition:

```
(defmacro with-eval-after-load-feature (feature &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  (let* ((feature (if (and (listp feature) (eq (car-safe feature) 'quote))
                      (cdr feature) feature))
         (fs (if (listp feature) feature (list feature)))
         (form (or (and (eval '(eval-when (compile)
                                 (with-eval-after-load-feature-preload fs)))
                        'with-no-warnings)
                   'progn)))
    `(,form ,@(with-eval-after-load-feature-transform fs body))))
```

in [this file](https://github.com/tarao/with-eval-after-load-feature-el/blob/master/with-eval-after-load-feature.el).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used for splicing in backquoted expressions. See `C-h i g (elisp) Backquote RET`. For example:

```
elisp> `(1 2 ,(list 3 4))  ; no splicing => nested list
(1 2
   (3 4))

elisp> `(1 2 ,@(list 3 4)) ; splicing => flat list
(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: It can also help to say that `,@` is essentially the same as `, .` (which you can also use).

Comment: @Drew, do you mean `, .` or  `. ,` as in `(1 2 .,(list 3 4))`? The first one doesn't work in Emacs Lisp (works in CL, though), the second one will only work if the splice is at the end.

Comment: Yes to both things you said. I meant **`.  ,`**, and of course only one thing can follow `.`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The comment also put it nicely in context.

Answer (score 3):

Asking Emacs is always a sensible approach:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>I</kbd> `@` <kbd>RET</kbd>

This shows you all the `elisp` manual's index entries for `@` (one of which is the `,@` you were actually looking for).