# What does the `@` mean in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Quite likely this is a dumb question, but I haven't come across the `@` symbol in the bits of elisp I have read, and was wondering what it means (preceded by a `,` as well) in this [code](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs/blob/master/zenburn-theme.el#L86)?  I have had some difficulty providing the proper search phrase I think.

In case of link rot:

```
(defmacro zenburn-with-color-variables (&rest body)
  "`let' bind all colors defined in `zenburn-colors-alist' around BODY.
Also bind `class' to ((class color) (min-colors 89))."
  (declare (indent 0))
  `(let ((class '((class color) (min-colors 89)))
         ,@(mapcar (lambda (cons)
                     (list (intern (car cons)) (cdr cons)))
                   zenburn-colors-alist))
     ,@body))
```

Comment: Great question. And there still isn't a very cogent answer to the question in the top Google search results for nearly fours years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an elisp macro definition, it defines a template for code to be substituted by other code at compile time. A decent intro is chapter 7 of Paul Graham's *On Lisp*

http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html

Comment: No, the @ (actually, it's the ,@ together) is part of the macro templating language. ,@body means 'put the elements of the list body here when expanding the macro'.

Answer (score 1):

Ask Emacs, by checking the index of the elisp manual:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>I</kbd> `@` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Follow result: `* ,@ (with backquote) [Index]: Backquote. (line 29)`

```
You can also "splice" an evaluated value into the resulting list,
using the special marker ‘,@’.  The elements of the spliced list become
elements at the same level as the other elements of the resulting list.
The equivalent code without using ‘`’ is often unreadable.  Here are
some examples:
[...]
```

Comment: You posted [practically the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33592838/874188) very recently. Please flag as duplicate instead of repeating the same answer.

Comment: tripleee: Ah, thank you. I had thought as much, but used the wrong search terms and didn't find it.

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure this is really a dupe because the OP here isn't familiar with the macro facility at all and the answer addresses that. The person asking the other question is and the answers thus are different.

Comment: @pvg I really don't see that.  This question is about a `defmacro` call so there has to be at least some superficial familiarity. If you have this question you clearly haven't seen a lot of macros anyway. You are certainly welcome to port your answer to the other question as well if you think it's relevant and useful (though to my mind, it would fit better as a comment).

Comment: @tripleee the question is about @ and the trouble this person had finding an answer because it's nigh-ungoogleable. They were asking because they saw it in someone else's code, not because they knew defmacro. It's the other question that's actually kind of silly :) but perhaps no point arguing about it.

Comment: @slickrickulicious not really that important, no worries.